# rake migration error MaBase is not a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't found anything on this issue.
I create migration like this :
rails generate migration MaBase

And I fill the *_ma_base.rb like that

```
class MaBase < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
      create_table :connexion
      add_column :connexion, :ip, :string
      add_column :connexion, :user_agent, :string
      add_column :connexion, :nb, :integrer
      add_column :connexion, :date, :datetime
      create_table :recherche
      add_column :recherche, :ip, :string
      add_column :recherche, :recherche, :string
      add_column :recherche, :date, :datetime
      create_table :membre
      add_column :membre, :ip, :string
  end
end
```

And I get the error.

After reading some subject here, and i create create a file in model ma_base.rb with this kind of code :

```
class MaBase < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

But the error is stil here

Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

Change your `class` name in migration file from `MaBase` to `MaBases`. Activerecord maps plural of `model` names in db files. Try this:

```
class MaBases < ActiveRecord::Migration
```

Comment: Thanks but I get an other error now : NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for MaBase:Module

Comment: No just when I run rake db:migrate after addind "s"

Comment: did you also add `s` in migration filename?

Comment: please , accept and upvote my answer if it helped you. Thanks!